# Mrjob fails to create cluster on dataproc: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'channel'

Tags: python, python-3.x, mapreduce, google-cloud-dataproc, mrjob

I am trying to run the Hadoop Map Reduce word count example on Google Cloud Dataproc, using the Python `mrjob` library. However, `mrjob` fails with following exception:

```
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'channel'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "freq.py", line 21, in <module>
    MRWordFreqCount.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/mrjob/job.py", line 616, in run
    cls().execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/mrjob/job.py", line 687, in execute
    self.run_job()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/mrjob/job.py", line 636, in run_job
    runner.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/mrjob/runner.py", line 503, in run
    self._run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/mrjob/dataproc.py", line 468, in _run
    self._launch()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/mrjob/dataproc.py", line 473, in _launch
    self._launch_cluster()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/mrjob/dataproc.py", line 637, in _launch_cluster
    self._get_cluster(self._cluster_id)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/mrjob/dataproc.py", line 1188, in _get_cluster
    return self.cluster_client.get_cluster(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/mrjob/dataproc.py", line 376, in cluster_client
    return google.cloud.dataproc_v1beta2.ClusterControllerClient(
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'channel'
```

I checked that `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` was set correctly, APIs are enabled on Google Cloud and all required roles were set for the service account.

`mrjob` succeeds to upload the files to the Google Cloud Storage. But fails as soon it tries to create a new Dataproc cluster.

What could be possible wrong?

Command line to launch a `mrjob` on Dataproc:

```
$ python3 freq.py -r dataproc words.txt
```

Current Python environment:

```
$ python3 -VV
Python 3.8.5 (default, Jul 28 2020, 12:59:40)
[GCC 9.3.0]

$ pip3 list | grep google
google-api-core          1.23.0
google-auth              1.23.0
google-auth-oauthlib     0.4.2
google-cloud-core        1.4.3
google-cloud-dataproc    2.0.2
google-cloud-logging     1.15.1
google-cloud-storage     1.32.0
google-crc32c            1.0.0
google-pasta             0.2.0
google-resumable-media   1.1.0
googleapis-common-protos 1.52.0

$ pip3 list | grep mrjob
mrjob                    0.7.4
```

Answer (score 2):

The solution was to downgrade google-cloud-dataproc to 1.1.1.

After debugging into mrjob implementation, I discovered that mrjob version 0.7.4 calls the constructor of google.cloud.dataproc_v1beta2.ClusterControllerClient using an argument that was renamed on google-cloud-dataproc library since version 2.0.0.

How to downgrade with pip3:

```
$ pip3 install --force-reinstall --no-deps google-cloud-dataproc==1.1.1
```